# Find the standard matrix for the transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Find the standard matrix for the transformation that projects
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 2 \\ \end{bmatrix} 
\text{ to } 
\begin{bmatrix}2\\ 4 \\ \end{bmatrix}
$$

and

$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 1 \\ \end{bmatrix} 
\text{ to }
\begin{bmatrix}1\\ -1 \\ \end{bmatrix}
$$

The answer is \begin{bmatrix}0 && 1\\ -6 && 5 \end{bmatrix}

But I don't understand how they get to the answer.

Answer (score 6):

Let $T: \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$ the linear transformation, for which 
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix} \mapsto \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 4 \end{bmatrix} \; , \quad  \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \mapsto \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix} $$ 
holds. We will have to find the images of the standard basis 
$$\mathcal B = \left\{ \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} , \, \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \right\} \; .$$
We can write
$$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = (-1) \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix} + 2 \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \quad \text{and} \quad\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} = 1 \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix} + (-1) \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \; ,$$
so it follows that 
$$\begin{align*} 
T \left( \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \right) &= (-1) T \left( \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix} \right) + 2 T \left( \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \right) = - \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 4 \end{bmatrix} + 2 \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ -6 \end{bmatrix} \; , \\
T \left( \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \right) &= T \left( \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix} \right) - T\left( \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \right) = \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 4 \end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 5 \end{bmatrix} \; .
\end{align*} $$
Now we just have to write these vectors into the columns of our standard representation matrix $A_T$, and we get 
$$ A_T = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -6 & 5 \end{bmatrix} \; .$$

Comment: That couldn't have been more clear! Thank you!

Comment: @Jumba You can click "accept answer" on the left, to show future viewers that the question has been properly answered.

Answer (score 1):

Write the unknown matrix as 
$$A=\left( \begin{array}{cc}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{array} \right) $$
Take $$A\left(\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 2 \end{array} \right)=\left(\begin{array}{c} 2 \\ 4 \end{array} \right)$$ and $$A\left(\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 1 \end{array} \right)=\left(\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ -1 \end{array} \right)$$
Expanding out will give four equations in four unknowns, which is solvable. Hope this helps.